# Counting problem; $m, n (m<n) $ indistinguishable objects. How many ways are there to choose $r$ objects with repetition?

Tags: combinatorics

This is a counting problem. 
There are $m$ indistinguishable objects of type $1$ and $n$ indistinguishable objects of type $2$, where $m < n$. We choose $r$ objects with repetition. Then how many ways are there if the order of selection does not matter?

My guess is, $C(m+n+r-1,r)$, since it is considered to choose $r$ objects from $m+n$ with repetition; however, this problem suggest that 'consider cases: $r < m$, $m \leq r < n$, $n \leq r$)', but I did not know how to solve it with that range.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Is $AAABB$ the same as $ABAAB$ ?

Comment: Are you saying that we wish to select $r$ objects from two types of objects, where there are $m$ objects of type $1$ and $n$ objects of type $2$?

Comment: Yes, and those objects are indistinguishable. Furthermore, the order does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rephrase the question this way:

We have $m$ indistinguishable blue marbles and $n$ indistinguishable green marbles, with $m < n$.  In how many ways can we select $r$ of the $m + n$ marbles if the order of selection does not matter?

**Case 1:**  $r < m$.

Since marbles of the same color are indistinguishable and the order of selection does not matter, a selection is completely determined by the number of blue marbles.  Since $r < m$, the number of blue marbles we can select varies from $0$ to $r$, so there are $r + 1$ distinguishable selections of $r$ marbles.

Notice that the same argument applies if $r = m$, in which case the number of distinguishable selections is $m + 1$.

**Case 2:**  $m \leq r < n$

Since $m \leq r < n$ and only $m$ blue marbles are available, we must select at least $r - m$ green marbles.  We can select at most $r$ green marbles.  Thus, the number of possible selections is 
$$r - (r - m - 1) = m + 1$$

Alternatively, observe that we can select between $0$ and $m$ blue marbles, with the remainder being green, giving us $m + 1$ choices.

Notice that the same argument applies if $r = n$, so we also have $m + 1$ distinguishable selections in that case.

**Case 3:**  $r \geq n$

Since $r \geq n$, we must select at least $r - n$ blue marbles.  We can select at most $m$ blue marbles.  Hence, the number of possible selections is $$m - (r - n - 1)$$

Let's check the extreme cases.

If we select all the marbles, then $r = m + n$, so 
$$m - (r - n - 1) = m - (m + n - n - 1) = m - (m - 1) = 1$$
which makes sense since there is only one way to select all the marbles.

If $r = n$, then 
$$m - (r - n - 1) = m - (n - n - 1) = m - (-1) = m + 1$$
which makes sense since we can select from $0$ to $m$ blue marbles when we select $n$ marbles from a collection of $m$ blue marbles and $n$ green marbles.

Answer (score 0):

We want to choose $i$ objects from the $m$, and $r-i$ from the $n$, where $i$ can be any number between 0 and $\min(r,m)$.

There are $\binom{m}{i}$ ways to choose $i$ from the $m$, and $\binom{n}{r-i}$ ways to choose $r-i$ from the $n$. Then there would be $\binom{m}{i} \binom{n}{r-i}$ ways to choose $i$ objects from the $m$, and $r-i$ from the $n$.

And we need to sum up the numbers of combinations for all possible $i$ values. The result would be
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{i\leq min(r,m)} \binom{m}{i} \binom{n}{r-i} $$

Comment: In the comments, it says that the order in which the objects are selected does not matter.  Also, note that the $m$ objects of the first type are indistinguishable from each other, as are the $n$ objects of the second type.